# Lock screen does not work

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

Screen goes blank on screen lock according to the time it is set. The problem is that you press any key and screen comes on. No password needed. It is only screen off and not screen lock. I want the screen to lock(switch off and switched on only via a password.) Thanks. I am on ubuntu 18(Beaver)

Comment: Did you set `Automatic Login` to `ON` when installing 18.04?

Comment: The Automatic login is ON. I set the time on 30 seconds. Nothing happens. I close the laptop screen for 30 seconds, the screen is blank when opening. If I press any key the screen comes on. No password required.

Comment: When installing the Automatic Login was already on on,

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the correct settings in place in Setings > Privacy > Screen Lock.

[image]

Set to `On` with the other options set as required in the sub-menu which then opens.

If you have set the User account to  Automatic Login, you will need to select left Windows key and enter `users` on the search box (or use the search tool in `Settings`

This will produce the following screen. Select `Unlock` to make changes and set `Automatic Login` to `OFF`.

[image]

Comment: Screen lock is on. Screen does not lock when closing laptop or when screen goes off.